# Angular 4 store observable filled to early?

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, ngrx-store

I have this app where I have a store and a page component.

Having this page component:

```
import {AfterViewInit, Component, OnDestroy, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {ActivatedRoute, Params} from '@angular/router';
import {Store} from '@ngrx/store';
import {Translation, TranslationService} from 'angular-l10n';
import * as _ from 'lodash';
import * as moment from 'moment';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {of} from 'rxjs/observable/of';
import {Language, LoadLanguagesAction} from '../../../shared';
import {DateTimeFormatService} from '../../../shared';
import {TagsList} from '../../../shared/models/tags-list';
import * as fromRoot from '../../../shared/reducers';
import {LoadSubscriptionDetailAction, LoadSubscriptionDetailSuccessAction} from '../../actions/subscription';
import {EditSubscriptionForm} from '../../models/edit-subscription-form';
import {Subscriptions} from '../../models/subscriptions';
import * as fromSubscription from '../../reducers';
import {Subscription} from 'rxjs/Subscription';

@Component(
  { selector: 'storever-subscription-detail', templateUrl: './subscription-detail.component.html', styleUrls: ['./subscription-detail.component.scss'] })
export class SubscriptionDetailComponent extends Translation implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  subscription$: Observable<Subscriptions>;
  languages$: Observable<Language[]>;
  tagsList$: Observable<TagsList[]>;
  first: Subscriptions;
  private actionsSubscription: Subscription;
  name: string;
  created: string;
  update: string;
  createdP: string;
  updateP: string;
  createdS: string;
  updateS: string;

  constructor(private store: Store<fromSubscription.AppState>, private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, translation: TranslationService) {
    super(translation);
    this.actionsSubscription = activatedRoute.params.pluck<Params, string>('subscriptionId')
      .distinctUntilChanged()
      .switchMap(subscriptionId => of(new LoadSubscriptionDetailAction(subscriptionId)))
      .subscribe(store);
    this.subscription$ = this.store.select(fromSubscription.selectors.getSubscription);
    this.languages$ = this.store.select(fromRoot.selectors.getLanguages);
    this.tagsList$ = this.store.select(fromRoot.selectors.getTags);
    this.subscription$.subscribe(data => (data ? console.log('dataaaaaaaaaa', data) : null ), err => console.log('err', err));
    /*
    this.created = moment(this.subscription$.created).format('DD/MM/YYYY h:mm:ss');
    this.update = moment(this.subscription$.updated).format('DD/MM/YYYY h:mm:ss');
    this.createdP = moment(this.subscription$.player.created).format('DD/MM/YYYY h:mm:ss');
    this.updateP = moment(this.subscription$.player.updated).format('DD/MM/YYYY h:mm:ss');
    this.createdS = moment(this.subscription$.site.created).format('DD/MM/YYYY h:mm:ss');
    this.updateS = moment(this.subscription$.site.updated).format('DD/MM/YYYY h:mm:ss');
    */
  }
  get dateTimeWithSecondsAndTimezoneFormat(): string { return DateTimeFormatService.display.dateTimeWithSecondsAndTimezone; }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.store.dispatch(new LoadLanguagesAction());

  }



  ngOnDestroy() {
    super.cancelParamSubscriptions();
    this.actionsSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }

  saveMedia(subscriptions: EditSubscriptionForm): void {}
}
```

As service I have:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

import {AppSettingsService, BaseRestService, BlockUIService, SendBackResult} from '../../shared';
import {Subscriptions} from '../models/subscriptions';

@Injectable()
export class SubscriptionService extends BaseRestService {
  constructor(http: Http, appSettingsService: AppSettingsService, blockUIService: BlockUIService) { super(http, appSettingsService, blockUIService); }

  protected get className(): string { return 'MediaService'; }

  protected get isAnonymous(): boolean { return false; }

  load(clientId: string, subscriptionId: string): Observable<SendBackResult<Subscriptions>> {
    return this.get<Subscriptions>(`/clients/${clientId}/audio/subscriptions/${subscriptionId}`);
  }

  /*
  update(clientId: string, mediaId: number, media: Media): Observable<SendBackResult<Media>> {
    return this.put<Media>(`/clients/${clientId}/audio/media/commercials/${mediaId}`, media);
  }
  */
}
```

Reducer:

```
import {Action} from '@ngrx/store';
import * as _ from 'lodash';

import {UserContextActionTypes} from '../../shared';
import {
  LoadSubscriptionDetailAction,
  LoadSubscriptionDetailFailAction,
  LoadSubscriptionDetailSuccessAction,
  SubscriptionDetailActionTypes
} from '../actions/subscription';
import {Subscriptions} from '../models/subscriptions';

export interface SubscriptionsDetailState {
  value: Subscriptions;
  submitting: boolean;
}

const initialState: SubscriptionsDetailState = {
  value: undefined,
  submitting: false
};

export function SubscriptionDetailReducer(state = initialState, action: Action): SubscriptionsDetailState {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SubscriptionDetailActionTypes.LOAD_SUCCESS:
      return handleLoadSuccessAction(state, action);
    case SubscriptionDetailActionTypes.LOAD_FAIL:
      return handleLoadErrorActions(state);
    case UserContextActionTypes.CHANGE_CLIENT:
      return handleChangeClientAction();
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

function handleLoadSuccessAction(state: SubscriptionsDetailState, action: LoadSubscriptionDetailSuccessAction): SubscriptionsDetailState {
  const newState = _.clone(state);
  newState.value = action.payload;
  return newState;
}

function handleLoadErrorActions(state: SubscriptionsDetailState): SubscriptionsDetailState {
  const newState = _.clone(state);
  newState.value = undefined;
  return newState;
}

function handleChangeClientAction(): SubscriptionsDetailState {
  return { value: undefined, submitting: false };
}

export const SubscriptionDetailSelectors = {
  value: (state: SubscriptionsDetailState) => _.get<Subscriptions>(state, 'value'),
  submitting: (state: SubscriptionsDetailState) => _.get<boolean>(state, 'submitting', false)
};
```

Reducer index.ts:

```
import {ActionReducerMap, createFeatureSelector, createSelector, MemoizedSelector} from '@ngrx/store';
import * as _ from 'lodash';
import * as fromRoot from '../../shared/reducers';
import {SubscriptionFilter} from '../models/subscription-filter';
import {Subscriptions} from '../models/subscriptions';

import {SubscriptionsListReducer, SubscriptionsListSelectors, SubscriptionsListState} from './subscriptions';
import {SubscriptionDetailReducer, SubscriptionDetailSelectors, SubscriptionsDetailState} from './subscription';

export interface SubscriptionsState { subscriptions: SubscriptionsListState; subscription: SubscriptionsDetailState;}

export interface AppState extends fromRoot.AppState { subscriptions: SubscriptionsState; subscription: SubscriptionsDetailState; }

export const reducers: ActionReducerMap<SubscriptionsState> = {
  subscriptions: SubscriptionsListReducer,
  subscription: SubscriptionDetailReducer
};

const getCampaignsState = createFeatureSelector('campaigns');
const rootSelectors = {
  subscriptions: createSelector(getCampaignsState, (state: SubscriptionsState) => _.get<SubscriptionsListState>(state, 'subscriptions')),
  subscription: createSelector(getCampaignsState, (state: SubscriptionsState) => _.get<SubscriptionsDetailState>(state, 'subscriptions'))
};

export interface Selectors {
  getShowFilter: MemoizedSelector<AppState, boolean>;
  getQuickSearch: MemoizedSelector<AppState, string>;
  getFilter: MemoizedSelector<AppState, SubscriptionFilter>;
  getPage: MemoizedSelector<AppState, number>;
  getPageSize: MemoizedSelector<AppState, number>;
  getOrderBy: MemoizedSelector<AppState, string>;
  getCount: MemoizedSelector<AppState, number>;
  getSubscriptions: MemoizedSelector<AppState, Subscriptions[]>;
  getSubscription: MemoizedSelector<AppState, Subscriptions>;
}

export const selectors: Selectors = {
  getShowFilter: createSelector(rootSelectors.subscriptions, SubscriptionsListSelectors.showFilter),
  getQuickSearch: createSelector(rootSelectors.subscriptions, SubscriptionsListSelectors.quickSearch),
  getFilter: createSelector(rootSelectors.subscriptions, SubscriptionsListSelectors.filter),
  getPage: createSelector(rootSelectors.subscriptions, SubscriptionsListSelectors.page),
  getPageSize: createSelector(rootSelectors.subscriptions, SubscriptionsListSelectors.pageSize),
  getOrderBy: createSelector(rootSelectors.subscriptions, SubscriptionsListSelectors.orderBy),
  getCount: createSelector(rootSelectors.subscriptions, SubscriptionsListSelectors.count),
  getSubscriptions: createSelector(rootSelectors.subscriptions, SubscriptionsListSelectors.array),
  getSubscription: createSelector(rootSelectors.subscription, SubscriptionDetailSelectors.value),
};
```

Action is:

```
import {Action} from '@ngrx/store';

import {type} from '../../shared';
import {Subscriptions} from '..//models/subscriptions';

export const SubscriptionDetailActionTypes = {
  LOAD: type('[ Subscription] Load'),
  LOAD_SUCCESS: type('[ Subscription] Load Success'),
  LOAD_FAIL: type('[ Subscription] Load Fail')
};

export class LoadSubscriptionDetailAction implements Action {
  readonly type = SubscriptionDetailActionTypes.LOAD;
  constructor(public payload?: string) {}
}

export class LoadSubscriptionDetailSuccessAction implements Action {
  readonly type = SubscriptionDetailActionTypes.LOAD_SUCCESS;
  constructor(public payload?: Subscriptions) {}
}

export class LoadSubscriptionDetailFailAction implements Action {
  readonly type = SubscriptionDetailActionTypes.LOAD_FAIL;
  constructor(public payload?: number) {}
}
```

Effect:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Response} from '@angular/http';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import {Actions, Effect} from '@ngrx/effects';
import {Action, Store} from '@ngrx/store';
import {TranslationService} from 'angular-l10n';
import * as _ from 'lodash';

import {ArrayResponse, BaseEffect, error, SendBackResult} from '../../shared';
import * as fromRoot from '../../shared/reducers';
import {Subscriptions} from '..//models/subscriptions';
import {SubscriptionDetailActionTypes,
  LoadSubscriptionDetailFailAction,
  LoadSubscriptionDetailSuccessAction,
  LoadSubscriptionDetailAction} from '../actions/subscription';
import * as fromSubscriptions from '../reducers/';
import {SubscriptionService} from '../services/subscription.service';

@Injectable()
export class SubscriptionEffect extends BaseEffect {
  private client$ = this.store.select(fromRoot.selectors.getCurrentClient).filter(client => !_.isEmpty(client));


  @Effect()
  load$ = this.actions$.ofType(SubscriptionDetailActionTypes.LOAD)
    .delayWhen(() => this.client$)
    .debug('Load Subscription details action received.')
    .map((action: LoadSubscriptionDetailAction) => action.payload)
    .withLatestFrom(this.client$)
    .switchMap(([payload, client]) => this.subscriptionService.load(client.uuid, payload)
      .map((result: SendBackResult<Subscriptions>) => new LoadSubscriptionDetailSuccessAction(result.data))
      .catch((res: Response) => this.catchResponseError(res)));

  @Effect()
  loadFail$ = this.actions$.ofType(SubscriptionDetailActionTypes.LOAD_FAIL)
    .debug('A server error occurred while retrieving media details.')
    .map(() => error(this.translation.translate('SUBSCRIPTION_LOAD_ERROR'), this.translation.translate('TOAST_ERROR_TITLE')));

  constructor(private actions$: Actions,
              private store: Store<fromSubscriptions.AppState>,
              private translation: TranslationService,
              private subscriptionService: SubscriptionService,
              router: Router) {
    super(router);
  }

  protected handleUnhandledError(response: Response): Action { return new LoadSubscriptionDetailFailAction(response.status); }
}
```

So far so good. But chen I call the subscribe in the page component I do not get the console.log, even worse the subscription is not loaded, which means he does not know the name because it is not printed. I'm completly losed. The call happens everything is fine when I debug payload is always there yet, no subscribe on the this.subscription$

He tries to add it to soon, I think because he tries it before the call?

Added the image is the console.

[image: console of the app]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Index.ts was not set propely,

When having same bugs check if it's saved in store. If saved check selectors, because if it is in store you just need to get it out.

```
const rootSelectors = {
  subscriptions: createSelector(getCampaignsState, (state: SubscriptionsState) => _.get<SubscriptionsListState>(state, 'subscriptions')),
  subscription: createSelector(getCampaignsState, (state: SubscriptionsState) => _.get<SubscriptionsDetailState>(state, 'subscription'))
};
```